# How to link a exe to a button without having other people to download it Visual Studio 2015 (C# Windows Forms application)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I would like to know how someone would go about linking a button to an exe on their computer but the catch is if I do something like this `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/folder/EXE");` you will have to download the exe separately. What I would like is a way where you just open your program, press the button and you can load the external exe.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you not include the .exe in your bin and reference it using reflection on the current executing assembly? Are you trying to completely avoid the .exe being on their machine?

Comment: Its really easy in WPF (but can be done in any other desktop framework), you just embed the file as a resource. Then as noted below, just grab the resource as a byte[] array and write it via BinaryStream to a temporary file somewhere. Getting a temporary path from System.IO is a great way to ensure that no matter the users privledge level they will be able to write it out.

Comment: In your installer, install both applications at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you serialize your executable and write it to the client computer (for example, using `BinaryReader and BinaryWriter`), you can then use `Process.Start` to run it. This would allow you to write it to a temporary path using `Path.GetTempPath` and the client would perceive the launching as occurring directly from your application. Alternatively, you could check a fixed location such as C:/folder/EXE for the existence of the executable, and if it doesn't exist, write it there before launching it as normal.

Another option could be to host the file on a network share and launch it from there, depending on your use case - but that would require a reliable known network configuration and/or drive mapping on the client computers.

Comment: You should **never** use fixed folder outside of predefined folders.